# Swift: Remove text from string

Tags: swift

I have found numerous ways of removing the last letter/character from a string of text as well as replacing text. While I am aware I can do stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString, the issue with this method is I continuously receive different text. I am also aware of componentsSeparatedByString but I want to remove it, not separate it.

For example, a credit card is swiped and it gives me track data.

```
%B5555444433332211^TEST CARD/^2209502543219871234567890123455555444433332211=220950254321987123
```

I want to remove everything after the equals sign to look like this.

```
%B5555444433332226^TEST CARD/^2209502543219871234567890123455555444433332211
```

Any input is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `the issue with this method is I continuously receive different text` Do you mean that you could for example receive strings that have an `=` character *before* the one you want to stop at? Just to be sure about your question.

Comment: @Eric D. No, it is always going to be after the = sign. But the text is always going to be different is what I mean, if that makes sense

Comment: Makes perfect sense, and that's what I wanted to know, excellent. :) In this case I suggest you try @colavitam's link. Tell us if it worked for you. If it doesn't work there's plenty of other options - but it should work, just use `"="` instead of `" "`.